# How do I remove the cover on Chamberlain 9300 model CH-1000?

Tags: garage-door-opener

We recently purchased a home that has garage doors and openers.  I’m trying to access the back of the Chamberlain 9300 model CH-1000 and cannot find any clips or screws to take off the housing cover.  I am trying to get to the dip switches so I can adjust them. Our handyman had switched them and we needed another remote.  When I put the new remote dip switches in the same configuration as what the old remote had, the new one wouldn’t work and the old one stopped working.  The old one has a new 9 volt battery in it and was working fine.[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no back cover. To access the internals, the entire side and bottom panel has to be removed. If your unit has DIP switches they may be around the lights. Remove the front cover and check.

It is highly unlikely the switches, if any are on the unit, are inside the main cover. More likely the unit uses a memory technology and the unit and remotes have to be "synched" with each other.
Look for a "learn" button.

If you have the "learn" button there should also be instructions on the unit, or you will have to google the process for your opener and remote.

Comment: The dips are on the reverse end of the light bulb.  I’ve seen them. But I thought there might be an easier way to get to the switches.  Thank you!